# Accept international name characters in RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I've always struggled with RegEx so forgive me if this may seem like an awful approach at tackling my problem.

When users are entering first and last names I started off just using the basic, check for upper and lower case, white space, apostrophes and hyphens

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s'-]+$/", $name)) { // Error }
```

Now I realise this isn't the best since people could have things such as: Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr. (with comma's and fullstops). So I assume by changing it to this would make it slightly more effective.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'-]+$/", $name)) { // Error }
```

I then saw a girls name I know on my Facebook who writes her name as Siân, which got me thinking of names which contain umlauts as well as say Japanese/Chinese/Korean/Russian characters too. So I started searching and found ways by writing each of these characters in there like so.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\sàáâäãåèéêëìíîïòóôöõøùúûüÿýñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/u", $first_name)) { // Error }
```

As you can imagine, it's extremely long winded and I'm pretty certain there is a much simpler RegEx which can achieve this. Like I've said, I've searched around but this is the best I can do.

So, what is a good way to check for upper and lower case characters, commas, full stops, apostrophes, hypens, umlauts, Latin, Japanese/Russian etc

Comment: That WILL NOT WORK unless you normalize first, and often not even then.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use an Unicode character class. `\pL` covers pretty much all letter symbols.
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

```
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'-\pL]+$/u", $name))
```

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html, but beware that PHP/PCRE only understands the abbreviated class names.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, why couldn't I find this earlier, ha! Could you tell me what you mean by abbreviated class names?

Comment: @HelloJoe: It's not the most obvious feature. Only found the documentation in the PHP manual pretty late. Abbreviations: PCRE only supports `\p{L}` not `\p{Letter}` or `\p{Russian}` for example.

Comment: You have `,.'` in there, you might want to remove it as it is a name.

Comment: perfect, thank you. but expression contain a small error, 
correct one: `/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'\-\pL]+$/u`
or `/^[a-z\s,.'-\pL]+$/iu`

Comment: it doesn't cover æøå or ß

Answer (score 7):

`\pL` already includes `a-z` and `A-Z`, therefore the mentioned pattern `"/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'-\pL]+$/u"` could be simplified to

`"/^[\s,.'-\pL]+$/"`

also the modifier `u` is not required.

Comment: Though I initially intended to +1 due to the mention of `a-zA-Z` being redundant, I must mention that the `u` modifier is certainly required as otherwise PHP does not support multi-byte encodings.

Comment: I tested it on my DEV machine and it worked for me event without the `u` modifier

Comment: Were you using a UTF-8 or other multibyte encoding, or a single-byte encoding such as ASCII or latin1? The `u` modifier is not necessary for single-byte encodings.

Answer (score 3):

There could probably be some loosening of the qualifications by allowing other types of punctuation.

One thing that should be a restriction is requiring at least one letter.

`if (!preg_match("/^[\s,.'-]*\p{L}[\p{L}\s,.'-]*$/u", $name))`