# Any difference between returning False or True first?

Tags: php, regex, function, return-value

I have the following function.
I can run it to test if true, or else false or vice versa as shown.

```
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];

function namecheck ($fname,$lname) 
{    
    $names= array ($fname,$lname);

    $regexp ="/^[A-Za-z]+$/";

    //filter through names 
    for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
    if (! preg_match($regexp, $names[$i])) 
    {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**(Alternate Version):**

```
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
if (preg_match($regexp, $names[$i])) 
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Which is the better way to write this, both in terms of efficiency and good coding practices? Or is there no difference?

It may not be an issue for a small array like this, but I am wondering what effect it would have on a larger and more complex program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that both the loops are checking for different results.

- The 1<sup>st</sup> loop is checking whether the `$regexp` matches all the elements of the array - In this case, it returns `false` as soon as a match fails and if the return statement after the for loop is reached, that means all the elements match.
  To be honest, not having the braces around the `for` loop can often be confusing (like it confused me first). I would suggest to add relevant brace:

  ```
  for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
      if (preg_match($regexp, $names[$i])) {
           return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
  ```
- The 2<sup>nd</sup> loop is checking whether the `$regexp` matches any element of the array - In this case, it return `true` as soon as a match succeeds, and if the return statement after the for loop is reached, that means none of the elements match.

  ```
  for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
      if (! preg_match($regexp, $names[$i])) {
           return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
  ```

Comment: @Skippy. Check out your loops. In both the cases, if `if` condition is evaluated to `true`, if will return the value from `if` block, and if the condition is false, it won't go inside the `if` block, and execute the last statement in for loop, which will return something else. In any case, your loop will only iterate once.

Comment: @Skippy. Oh! great. I didn't see that you don't have curly braces around the `for` loop. I mistakenly took the closing braces of method, as closing braces of `for` loop.

Comment: @Skippy. That's why you should never remove the braces from the loop. It will only confuse people.

Comment: RohitJain nicely done +1 ... @Skippy there is many bad practice in your code in your code .. i see no reason to not validate input you should first check weather $_POST is set your not

Comment: @Skippy thankyou .. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8013972/1723893 if you are targeting international people name than name can have words other than a-z and about the function and loop i am agree with Rohit .. so adding another answer wouldnt be worthy :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code you would check only one iteration ($i = 0)

You could use:

```
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    if (!preg_match($regexp, $names[$i])) return false;
}
return true;
```

If there would be error method would return false, if no -> true. Method would stop iteration on first error.

Comment: In fact I saw many same errors in code. 
So no, I didn't look at your question before ) only experience )

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to *give your function a name that makes more sense*, like is_name_valid(). It helps clarity and your "problem" will instantly go away since it will have to return True when  the name satisfies your requirements or False otherwise.

Comment: I actually use camelCase myself, I only wanted to follow the style of the code in the question ("namecheck").