# Invalid range in character class Regex Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I got Invalid range in character class issue when trying to use regex

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯЁё0-9_-\s]{6,20}$/
```

But the issue is only in Firefox, in Chrome it's ok.

With this regex I am trying to say "only latin, russian letters, numbers, space and '_' and '-' signs allowed"

Comment: Try to put the `-` at the end or at the begining of the class or escape it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accept international name characters in RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013897/accept-international-name-characters-in-regex)

Comment: Thanks Casimir that was the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_-\s` is creating a range between the underscore and space characters.  You need to either escape the `-` as in `_\-\s` or put it at the end:

```
[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯЁё0-9_\s-]
```

Also beware of the `а-я` range.  If this is the same as the Latin 1 `a` the range may not be what you expect at all.