# preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 15

Tags: regex, expression, preg-match

I am getting this error while validating name.... I had searched regular expression for international name few months ago and finally got something working here : [Accept international name characters in RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013897/accept-international-name-characters-in-regex)

but now its showing me this error, Please help

preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 15

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'-\pL]+$/u", $name)) {
    return true;
} else{
    $this->addError($field_name.' contains invalid characters');
    return false;
}
```

also try this preg_match("/^[\s,.'-\pL]+$/", $name) but still showing same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hyphen (`-`) needs to be escaped because of its position inside of the character class.

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special meaning**. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'\-\pL]+$/u", $name)) { ...
                             ^^
```

You could write the regular expressions as follows:

```
if(preg_match("/^[\pL\s,.'-]+$/u", $name)) { ...
```

Comment: thank you so much.. I searched almost an hour for the solution and you solve this instantly thank you!

Comment: Is it ok if i use preg_match("/^[\pL\s,.'-]+$/u") as you mentioned.

Comment: I don't see why not =)